# What is the meaning of 言语间充满了骄傲?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

如此大手笔的推广，腾讯自有其底气所在。微信“在海外注册用户已经超过7000万，且在快速增长当中”。7月3日，在北京召开的2013腾讯合作伙伴大会上，腾讯总裁刘炽平言语间充满了骄傲。

Hi all. This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, chapter 12.

Please help me translate this: 言语间充满了骄傲

I am here:

腾讯(Tencent)总裁(president)刘炽平(Liu Chiping)言语(speech)间(in)充满了(was full of)骄傲(pride)

But it does not make sense. What means "speech in was full of pride?

提前感谢。

Answer (score 1):

I think you've pretty much understood it correctly.  [Chinese Zero to Hero course](https://chinesezerotohero.teachable.com/courses/302482/lectures/5181044) (paid service) gives two translations of this sentence; one includes:

> **Pride is evident in the words of Tencent's CEO Liu Chiping.**  (see: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqJ64l.png))

And another one in their pdf:

> With such large style of promotion, Tencent had their confidence in this matter. WeChat “has over 70 million users registered overseas, still growing rapidly”. On July 3rd, in the Beijing 2013 Tencent Cooperative Partner Assembly, **Tencent president Liu Chiping’s was full of pride in his words**.

It means you can tell from his manner of speaking (his choice of words, his tone, etc.) that he was brimming with pride.  In this context, it seems he was proud of Tencent's success.

When studying HSK levels 5 and 6, you encounter a lot of phrasings like 言语间 (~"in [his] words"; here 间 is being used as a suffix; see also [YouDao example sentences](https://youdao.com/result?word=lj:%E8%A8%80%E8%AF%AD%E9%97%B4&lang=en)), which express things flexibly and in unfamiliar ways, and might not be easily translated.  The other thing you might want to pay attention to, is that some of these articles are modified from an original, and have vocabulary forced into them in unnatural ways.  In this case, the original is mostly the same, but with 不乏 = "not short of" replaced by 充满了 = "brimming with":

> 如此大手笔的推广，腾讯自有其底气所在。“WeChat（微信的英文名）在海外注册用户已经超过7000万，且在快速增长当中。”7月3日，在北京召开的2013腾讯合作伙伴大会上，**腾讯总裁刘炽平言语间不乏骄傲**。
> <sub>[7000万海外用户玩微信 互联网崛起“中国制造”](http://finance.people.com.cn/n/2013/0704/c1004-22071442.html), 2013.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

A person has pride **in** something. He, as boss, will obviously have great pride **in** his (very successful) company.

He was full of pride. He was proud. A speech has no emotions and cannot feel pride.

间：在一定空间或时间内 in a certain space or time

in a certain time = during

腾讯总裁刘炽平言语间充满了骄傲。
Tencent Chairman Liu Chiping, during his speech, was full of pride.

Answer (score 1):

Again, the confusion is caused by the "unique sentence structure" in the Chinese language, which can not be translated into other languages word by word without a little twist. I'll segmentize the sentence as:

"腾讯总裁刘炽平 **言语间** 充满了骄傲。" Note that in this structure, the phrase "言语间" is an orphan, which could be modified to "腾讯总裁刘炽平**的言语**充满了骄傲。" - His talk filled with pride, or "**言语间**, 腾讯总裁刘炽平充满了骄傲。" - "In the speech, he is full of pride".

Hope this explanation makes sense.